# SQL Server 2008 Express server information

Tags: sql-server-2008, server-name

I installed a company specific program which can connect to a SQL Server. I installed SQL Server 2008 Express with mixed authentication. I called the instance `SQLExpress`.

What I want to do is to create a new database via the program. (see image). In point 5 I tried many logins like `sa-login`, `MyComputerName\User-Password`, `User-Pass`, but nothing works. In point 6 I used for the server name `SQLExpress` or `MyComputerName\SQLExpress` and for the (new) database name I used `MyDB`, but same thing here. Can't connect.

It keeps saying:

> cannot create database master.MyDB. SQL Server doesn't exist or access denied.

Can anyone help me please?

Image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/248/sqlserverinfo.png/

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I've created a user in SQL Server and added him to the "sysadmin"
role and gave him access to the "master" database.
After that I added an inbound rule (allow port 1433) to my Windows Firewall to allow remote connections to the SQL Server.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx